# C# wait 1 second

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there such a function like sleep(seconds) but it wouldn't block UI updates?
I have a code like this and if I put threading sleep after `(letters.Children[Words[index].index] as TextBlock).Text = Words[index].LetterCorrect;` (I want to sleep after that) it just waits 1 sec and then UI gets updates, but I dont want that.

```
private void Grid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (index == Words.Count() - 1) return;
    if ((((e.Source as Button).Content as Viewbox).Child as Label).Content.ToString() == Words[index].LetterCorrect)
    {
        (letters.Children[Words[index].index] as TextBlock).Text = Words[index].LetterCorrect;

        letters.Children.Clear();
        LoadWord(++index);
        this.DataContext = Words[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to send a different thread to sleep and not the UI thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a Timer and have the Elapsed callback execute the code you want to happen after the one second.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Create a working thread that does the work for you and let that thread sleep for the desired time before going to work

e.g.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                // do your work here
                // CAUTION: use Invoke where necessary
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic itself in a background thread separate from the UI thread and have that thread wait.

Anything in the UI thread that waits 1 second will lock up the entire UI thread for that second.

Answer (score 1):

Use an async scheduled callback:

```
private void Grid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (index == Words.Count() - 1) return;
    if ((((e.Source as Button).Content as Viewbox).Child as Label).Content.ToString() == Words[index].LetterCorrect)
    {
        (letters.Children[Words[index].index] as TextBlock).Text = Words[index].LetterCorrect;

        Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(schedule =>
        {
           letters.Children.Clear();
           LoadWord(++index);
           this.DataContext = Words[index];

        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What namespace does it use? System.Reactive.Concurrency?

Comment: Hm, but there isn't anything like that in autocomplete.. Do I need to add reference or something?

Comment: You probably need System.Reactive

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what framework you are using, but if you are using Silverlight or WPF, have you considered playing an [animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) that reveals the correct letter or does a fade sequence that takes 1000ms?

Comment: Yes, it's WPF. Interesting idea, btw, Thanks!